# ¿Cómo limito el template al grupo del usuario?

Tags: django

Necesito limitar parte del template a los usuarios miembros de un grupo.

Sería algo similar a lo siguiente, pero para el grupo del usuario:

```
{% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes encontrar los grupos en:

```
{{ request.user.groups }}
```

Una manera muy rapida si sabes que los usuarios solo tendrán un grupo podria ser:

```
{% if 'grupo' ==  request.user.groups.all.0.name %}  
    parte restringida  
{% endif %}
```

Si es un poco mas complejo que eso, te recomeindo crearte una templatetag para preguntar en la template. (eso o lo llevas en una variable desde back)

Creas un fichero user_tags.py en tu proyecto debajo de nombreapp/templatetags

```
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django import template

register = template.Library()
@register.filter('has_group')
def has_group(user, group_name):
    """
    Verifica se este usuário pertence a un grupo
    """
    groups = user.groups.all().values_list('name', flat=True)
    return True if group_name in groups else False
```

Y en la template lo usas:

```
{% load user_tags %} 
{% if request.user|has_group:"Administradores"%}
      parte restringida  
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Gracias por responder. En mi caso tengo los usuarios repartidos en 3 grupos, pero es un grupo por usuario. Voy a probar lo del user_tag